# run whereHas laravel method on large data set downs mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crash, laravel-5.3

I have a `Conversation` model like this :

```
class Conversation extends Model
{
        use SoftDeletes;

        protected $primaryKey = 'conversation_id';
        protected $dates      = ['deleted_at', 'expert_read_at', 'expert_admin_read_at'];
        protected $fillable   = ['code', 'expert', 'expert_read_at', 'expert_admin', 'expert_admin_read_at'];

        public function questions (){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Question','conversation_id','conversation_id');
        }
}
```

And a Question model like this :

```
class Question extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        protected $primaryKey = 'question_id';
        protected $dates      = ['deleted_at', 'confirmed_expert_admin_at'];
        protected $fillable   = ['text', 'answer', 'conversation_id', 'confirmed', 'is_private', 'email', 'confirmed_expert_admin_at'];

        public function conversation ()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Conversation', 'conversation_id', 'conversation_id');
        }
    }
```

As you can see there is a `hasMany` relationship between `Conversation` and `Question` models.

In the mysql database I have about **34,000** records for `Conversation` and each them have at least one related `Question`.

In the other hand on front-end there is a form that user can input a text to search through question `text` field.

Now I want to select conversations that have at least a question In accordance with the user input and then paginate results.

For that I wrote :

```
function SearchQuestion (Request $request)
            {
                $page            = $request->get('page');
                $questionPerPage = $request->get('question-per-page');
                $text            = $request->get('question-search-text');

                $conversations =
                    Conversation::whereHas('questions', function ($q) use ($text) {
                        if (!empty($text)) {
                            if (!is_numeric($text)) {
                                $q->where('text', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
                                    ->where('is_private', 0)
                                    ->where('answer', '<>', '')
                                    ->where(function ($q1) {
                                        $q1->where('confirmed', 1)
                                            ->orWhere('confirmed_expert_admin_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay());
                                    });
                            }
                        } else {
                            $q
                                ->where('is_private', 0)
                                ->where('answer', '<>', '')
                                ->where(function ($q1) {
                                    $q1->where('confirmed', 1)
                                        ->orWhere('confirmed_expert_admin_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay());
                                });
                        }
                    }
                    );

                if (!empty($text) and is_numeric($text)) {
                    $conversations->whereCode($text);
                }

                $conversations->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

                $conversations = $conversations->paginate(5);

                return $conversations;
    }
```

As you can see I used a `whereHas()` method to search in questions of each conversations.

But every time I run above query, in the first try , It takes a long time to execute query about **12 seconds** and in the next tries does not return any result and mysql crashes and I have to restart WAMP.

However, I'd Next want to select Questions of each selected Conversation using `with()` laravel method. In this case, I do not know how long it will take to execute query?

I am using **laravel 5.3** and wamp **3.0.6** (Apache 2.4.23 – PHP 5.6.25/7.0.10 – MySQL 5.7.14 ) on windows 8 ,64 bit .

What is the problem?What can I do?

**UPDATE:**
I add index to primary keys and foreign keys on two tables and all things worked fine.

Comment: what does `dd($conversations->toSql())` gave you? (put that `dd(..)` on the line just before `$conversations->paginate(5);`)

Comment: @BagusTesa, that returned **"select * from `conversations` where exists (select * from `questions` where `questions`.`conversation_id` = `conversations`.`conversation_id` and `text` LIKE ? and `is_private` = ? and `answer` <> ? and (`confirmed` = ? or `confirmed_expert_admin_at` <= ?) and `questions`.`deleted_at` is null) and `conversations`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc"**

Comment: @A.B.Developer try running that query in `phpadmin` or something to see if mysql is the problem. See if all the `id`s are indexed. Try it in different system as the crash could be because of your mysql instance.

Comment: weird, that query should fine although `LIKE` on large text column is a bit.. @Cerlin Boss is right try to run it on the `phpmyadmin` directly. (change that `?` with proper value though)

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes. Please try it and post the results as a `crash` sounds interesting.

Comment: I tried it on `phpmyadmin` directly and it takes long time to execute query so while I am writing this comment query is loading!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Add `with()` before whereHas.

```
 Conversation::with('questions')->whereHas('questions', function ($q) use ($text) {
              //your conditions on questions rows
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to adapt Eagerloading like this.

```
$conversations = Conversation::with(['questions' => function ($q) use ($text) {
    if (!empty($text)) {
        if (!is_numeric($text)) {
            $q->where('text', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%')
                ->where('is_private', 0)
                ->where('answer', '<>', '')
                ->where(function ($q1) {
                    $q1->where('confirmed', 1)
                        ->orWhere('confirmed_expert_admin_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay());
                });
        }
    } else {
        $q
            ->where('is_private', 0)
            ->where('answer', '<>', '')
            ->where(function ($q1) {
                $q1->where('confirmed', 1)
                    ->orWhere('confirmed_expert_admin_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDay());
            });
    }
}]);
```

Try this and see if the server load get reduced.